# Передача context в методы

Tags: java, android

Не до конца понимаю проблему с утечкой памяти из-за передачи контекста в статические методы. Понимаю что нет универсального совета и нужно смотреть код но может кто даст ссылку на внятное обьяснение.

Например у меня есть Singleton класс `DB` где каждый раз нужно передавать контекст

```
    public DB(Context ctx) {
        mCtx = ctx;
    }
```

Так вот почему не принято следующее:

```
public class AppContext {

        private static Context sContext;
        private static Application sApplication;

        public static Context getContext() {
            return sContext;
        }

        public static void setContext(Context context) {
            sContext = context;
        }

        public static Application getApplication() {

            return sApplication;
        }

        public static void setApplication(Application application) {
            sApplication = application;
        }
}
```

И в главной активити выполнить setContext и setApplication и использовать потом в DB AppContext.getApplication() вместо передачи контекста каждый раз?

Comment: Почитайте https://possiblemobile.com/2013/06/context/

Answer (score 2):

Если держать "жесткую" ссылку на Context, т.е Activity - то активити не сможет быть уничтожена. Вообще, вам следует почитать про достижимость обьектов по ссылке, про [weak and soft references (первое что под руку попало)](http://www.quizful.net/post/java_reference_types). Короче, очень плохо ** жестко держать** ссылку на активити тем более в статическом поле, поэтому всячески старайтесь избегать этого. На первый взгляд, вроде ничего страшного, но что если в активити куча ресурсов, фотографий высокого разрешения и тд ? Утечка памяти, и не дай бог OutOfMemoryError =)

Также помните, что статические поля - это зло, и очень коварное. Старайтесь вообще от статики по-дальше держаться.
В данном случае, вообще, пожалуй нет необходимости лепить конструкцию, выше указанную. Для работы с базой, берите контекст прямо в месте работы с базой -> работайте -> закрывайте базу -> освобождайте Context

Например, если уж вы передаете в конструкторе контекст в свой класс DB, то после того как поработали с базой, вам стоит занулять его, чтоли...

Answer (score 0):

Незнаю правильно но ли я Вас понял, но попробуйте лучше посмотреть в сторону Dependency Injection. Сам с андройд никогда не сталкивался, но вот нашел что под андройд тоже есть Spring (http://projects.spring.io/spring-android/). Это отличный DI фреймверк который позволяет избавитьсь от всех проблем с передачей или хранием контекста.